# I/O operation on closed file using input()

Tags: python-3.x, input

I have code that sets up an environment for running and logging scientific experiments. Some of the initial setup involves using the built in input() method to query the user for values. I keep getting a I/O operation on closed file error whenever I try to call input however.
Code flow: Control.py calls Analyzer.py which calls a specific method in Prompts.py (the code for which is below).

```
def prompt_instruments(message):
    res = input(message) # query user with arg message
    print("done")
    if '.' in res:
        print("User input not cool. Use comma-separated values.")
        return None # to continue prompting
...
```

I have searched all over the internet and have been unable to find anything remotely related. Thank you so much!!

Comment: For others who might encounter this problem, I found a call to exit() down a different, earlier, call stack which caused this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted seems ok, and the error is probably in one of your other files.

The `input()` function uses `sys.stdout` to display the prompt text, and `sys.stdin` to get the user's input text.

The error message you get is probably caused by one of these files being closed, e.g.:

```
>>> import sys
>>> input('test: ')
test: hello
'hello'
>>> sys.stdin.close()
>>> input('test: ')
test: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

or:

```
>>> import sys
>>> input('test: ')
test: hi
'hi'
>>> sys.stdout.close()
>>> input('test: ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I can't tell you exactly where to fix this issue, but look for things that might close one of these file, either directly or indirectly (e.g. context manager).

Comment: I never reference sys.stdout in any of the three scripts. Could you expand what you mean by indirectly closing. I use with statements, but never with anything tied to sys.

Comment: @ZoePlaxco Is there a way you could reduce these other 2 scripts to version that still reproduces the issue, and can share here?

Comment: And by "indirectly" I meant you are not calling `.close()` yourself, but something else is doing it behind the hood. An example (silly, but you get the point) would be using the [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that elsewhere in the code someone else had called exit() which under the hood closes sys.stdout